# Permission Error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: what could be the reason?

Tags: python

When downloading a file through a proxy to different folders, an error occurs:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "e:\proba.py", line 25, in
>
> save_file(link1)   File "e:\proba.py", line 16, in save_file
> open(r'\Users\user\Desktop\good\gg.jpeg', 'wb').write(r.content) PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
> '\Users\user\Desktop\good\gg.jpeg'

The code itself:

```
import requests

def save_file(link):
    filename = link.split('/')[-1]
    print(filename)
    proxies ={
        'https': 'http://135.181.14.45:5959'        
    }
    data = requests.get('https://ipinfo.io/json', proxies=proxies)
    print(data.text)
    r =requests.get(link,allow_redirects=True, proxies=proxies)
    print(r.status_code)

    while True:
        if(r.status_code == 200):
            open(r'\Users\user\Desktop\good\gg.jpeg', 'wb').write(r.content)
        if(r.status_code != 200):
            open(r'\Users\user\Desktop\bad\gg.jpeg', 'wb').write(r.content)
            break

    open(r'\Users\user\Desktop\general\gg.jpeg', 'wb').write(r.content)


link1 ='https://sport-dog.ru/wp-content/uploads/6/d/8/6d8d7be84e48acbf00a13444d45404f3.jpeg' 
save_file(link1)
```

Files are uploaded to three different folders through a proxy, but this error appears.

Comment: Try using `with open` instead of `open`. When using open, you need to close the file manually after whatever operation you perform. I can't really make out the intended indentation but my guess is that you get the Permission Error because the file is still open from a previous operation

Comment: This might be a permission issue in the file system level of your server. You have to grant the correct privileges to the user who is writing the files (some system user depending on your setup) for all involved paths.

Comment: Thanks! Can you tell me how to use it correctly here "with open" after "as f" swears due to the fact that the cycle continues in the next line goes "if"

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reuse your snippet and execute it. Please note that I have commented out few things like the last `open` line and also have removed the proxies. It worked for me without the proxies, but you can try it on your end with proxies enabled. Also what I can see from the error is that, it could be due to permission issue on your system level for the respective path/user:

```
import requests

def save_file(link):
    filename = link.split('/')[-1]
    print(filename)
    proxies ={
        'https': 'https://135.181.14.45:5959'
    }
    data = requests.get('https://ipinfo.io/json')
    print(data.text)
    r =requests.get(link,allow_redirects=True)
    print(r.status_code)
    print(r.content)

    while True:
        if(r.status_code == 200):
            open(r'jpg/good/good.jpeg', 'wb').write(r.content) <-- change to your path
            break
        if(r.status_code != 200):
            open(r'jpg/bad/bad.jpeg', 'wb').write(r.content) <-- change to your path
            break

    #open(r'\Users\user\Desktop\general\gg.jpeg', 'wb').write(r.content)


link1 ='https://sport-dog.ru/wp-content/uploads/6/d/8/6d8d7be84e48acbf00a13444d45404f3.jpeg' 
save_file(link1)
```

Output:

[image]

**Also I saw a typo in your proxies**

```
proxies = {
    'https': 'https://135.181.14.45:5959' # here for the value you had http and not https
}
```

Additionally its better if you use the `with open` option for file handling since it automatically closes all your file connectors:

```
with open(r'jpg/good/good.jpeg', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```